# Selenium Chrome Driver in Python doesn't find the xpath or id

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I'm new into python/selenium and I want to automatize some repetitive task at my job. The first that I'm trying to do is to login automatically to our internal business object platform but I can't pass from trying to click on the username and sendKeys

**1st try that fail**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

enter code here`username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_id0:logon:USERNAME"]')
enter code here`username.click()
enter code here`username.sendKeys("merle-dog")
```

**error:**

```
enter code here`elenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate 
element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="_id0:logon:USERNAME"]"}



**Element:**
`<input type="text" id="_id0:logon:USERNAME" name="_id0:logon:USERNAME">
```

don't have a clue why the element is not even found?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong locator.
I have no idea what are the actual attributes of that element, but `//*[@id="_id0:logon:USERNAME"]` is not seems to be a valid XPath locator.
This is why Selenium fails to find it.
But before this: Where is `driver.get(url)` command?
Where is driver instantiation?
Also all these `enter code here` are not looking like a part of Selenium code.